# Number of interest

Tags: java, c, arrays, data-structures, runtime-error

This is a challenge I have solved, but I get a score of zero when I submit the code. It seems to produce the correct output when I run it on my local machine. I have solved it with C and Java. In case of java the server is responding with a NZEC error the reason of which is also unknown.

Input:
The first line contains a number `T` which is the number of test cases.
The next `T` lines each contain 3 integers `X`, `Y` and `N` separated by a single space.

Output: 
For each test case print the `N`th number of the sequence.

```
Constraints:
1) 1 <= T <= 10^6
2) 0 < N <= 50
3) 0 < X < 50
4) 0 <= Y < 3

Sample Input-  Sample Output-
1              34
3 2 7
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int array[10000], x, y, z, j;
  long long int testcase;
  scanf("%lld", &testcase);

  for (long long int v = 0; v < testcase; v++) {
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
    *array = (int)(calloc ((z + 100), sizeof(int *)));

    for (int i = 0; i < z + 100; i++) {
      array[i] = 0;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
      array[j] = y;
    }
    for (int l = j; l < z; l++) {
      array[l] = array[l - 1] + array[l - 2] + array[l - 3];
    }
    printf("%d ", array[(z - 1)]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is my code written in java--

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long testCases = Long.parseLong(sc.nextLine());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (long i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            int y = sc.nextInt();
            int z = sc.nextInt();
            int array[] = new int[z+1];
            long sum = 0;
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
                array[j] = y;
            }

            for (int l = j; l < z; l++) //add for loop in case of greater j values
            {
                array[l] = array[l - 1] + array[l - 2] + array[l - 3];

            }

            System.out.println (array[(z-1)] + " ");
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: "`N`th number of the sequence." Which sequence?

Comment: Why `long long int testcase;`? The range of `T` is well within a 32-bit `int`. And why haven't you checked the input values against their defined range, and the return value from `calloc()`? Maybe the **Judge** gave inputs that fried his computer.

Comment: `*array = (int)(calloc ((z+100),sizeof(int *)));` This makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @n.m. especially when `array` is already `int array[10000];`

Comment: then replace that with  `for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
    {
      array[i] = 0;
    }` and save a call to calloc. Still makes no difference to the output.

Comment: `then replace that with for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) { array[i] = 0; }` If you want me to submit the fixed version to the judge, please post the submission address.

Comment: Here is a good example of why you should **NOT** cast `calloc()` and friends in C. If you have compiler warnings enabled, you would see how bad `*array=calloc()` is. Yet you cast it to `(int)` and so the compiler is *forced to believe you*: no warning.

Answer (score 3):

declare array as `int *array;`

allocate it as `array = calloc(z + 100, sizeof(int *));`

free it at the end of the loop with `free(array), array = NULL;`

I don't know if your algorithm is correct, but the way you allocate memory is bogus, the memory allocated is not used at all and the computation is limited to the a size of 10000 ints.  If your get a value larger then 9900 for T, your code will exhibit undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You have a big problem in your calloc, that might not have impacted the automatic testing of your script (see previous answer from chqrlie). And your algorithm is quite complicated : why initializing to 0 when the next loops will overwrite it? why allocating an extra 100 rows in your array?

Also, your code has problem with low values of z.

For instance with x=1, you are filling the array:

```
  array[1]=array[0]+array[-1]+array[-2];
```

which causes a stack overflow.

Look carefully at low values, and maybe try to understand the algorithm as a math problem

In many cases you will return (2^(z-x)+1)*y except when x=1 or x=2.

EDIT: it seems after reading your more complete post on the following link that your algorithm satisfy only x=3:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82295/hacker-earth-challenge-number-of-interest